# Can I blur specific area of a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, blur

I want to blur a specific area of a bitmap. For e.g. I have 200x400 resolution bitmap and want to blur it to from middle like from the point 100x300 up to 50 points.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use **[RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html)** to blur bitmap in Android.

RenderScript is especially useful for applications performing image processing, computational photography, or computer vision. There are two ways we can access the Android RenderScript framework APIs:

Directly using android.renderscript API classes. These classes are available from Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher.
Alternatively, you can use android.support.v8.renderscript support package classes. The support library classes are available for devices running Android 2.2 (API level 8) and higher.

In order to use the Support Library RenderScript APIs, you must have Android SDK Tools revision 22.2 or higher and SDK Build-tools revision 18.1.0 or higher

The following code snippets can be used create a bitmap blur effect in Android using RenderScript API.

```
//Set the radius of the Blur. Supported range 0 < radius <= 25
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25f;

public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
    if (null == image) return null;

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
    final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

    //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

You can use the above code snippet to blur an ImageView as follows.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nature);
Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will look on to this. :)

Comment: We need to write custom Renderscript code to do selective area blur. Any leads on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Render script** will not work in every api level so please use this library to make blur iffect on image https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2192

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks for response. I will look on to this. :)

Comment: @Rakesh. I don't want to blur whole image. Specific part of the image. Have you any idea regarding that?

Comment: use this library to make blur  specific part of image  https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/642

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response..:)

Answer (score 0):

I used next options:

1. Crop Area from Bitmap
2. Blur Cropped Area
3. **Bonus:** Cut Cricle from Crop Area
4. Overlay Cropped Area

Functions which I found in the net:

Crop:

```
 Bitmap cropImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, point.getX() - radius, point.getY() - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
```

Blur:

```
public static Bitmap blur(Bitmap image, int radius) {
    if (null == image) return null;

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
    final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(getMainActivity());
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

    //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(radius);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Get Circle:

```
public static Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    float r = 0;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

**Final:**

```
public static Bitmap blurPoint(Bitmap image, Point point, int radius) {
        Bitmap cropImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, point.getX() - radius, point.getY() - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        Bitmap blurImage = blur(cropImage, 10);
        Bitmap circleImage = getCircularBitmap(blurImage);
        return putOverlay(image, circleImage, new Point(point.getX() - radius, point.getY() - radius));
}
```

I don't know what is this performance in this approach. But I tested painting this blur in paint mode, and it was ok without lags.